# Objective-C: Calculating hourly rate with NSDate and NSDecimalNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdecimalnumber

I have two instances of NSDate (a start time and an end time) and also one NSDecimalNumber (which represents the amount that was earned over the period of time between the two dates).  What I'm trying to do is calculate an hourly rate based on these three variables.  I've come up with something that works, but it feels to me a bit excessive and I wanted to know if there was an easier, more efficient way.  This is what I am doing now.

Calculating the amount of time between the two NSDates

```
NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = [endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
```

Converting this into hours

```
double hours = timeInSeconds / 3600;
```

Converting the hours double into an NSNumber

```
NSNumber *duration = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:hours];
```

Converting the NSNumber into an NSString

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *durationString = [duration descriptionWithLocale:locale];
```

Using this string to create an NSDecimalNumber

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimalDuration = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:durationString locale:locale];
```

Dividing the original NSDecimalNumber (result) by this new NSDecimalNumber representation of time

```
NSDecimalNumber *hourlyRate = [result decimalNumberByDividingBy:decimalDuration];
```

If I'm understanding correctly, the only way to do any math involving my original NSDecimalNumber is to create another instance of NSDecimalNumber, so it is necessary to go through all these steps.  I'm worried that I might be losing accuracy or performing unnecessary steps.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a simple mathematics?

```
NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = [endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
double hours = timeInSeconds / 3600;
double rate = [result doubleValue];
double hourlyRate = rate / hours;
```

Comment: Yes I suppose this will work better.  I think I tricked myself into going down the longer path because I was trying to store the hourlyRate as a decimal core data transient value, but I believe it will be easier to use your method and just store it as a double wrapped in an NSNumber. Thank you,

Comment: @Mark Leonard, Glad it helped you :-)

Comment: @Mark: If you're doing multiple serious monetary calculations, you _will_ want to stick with decimal numbers, because you'll lose precision and then accuracy with doubles. Doing just one division step involving money should be fine, though.